# Dealing with Negative Forecasts in Positive-Valued Datasets

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret

I am forecasting a dataset with positive values in R using the Caret package, which applies machine learning algorithms. The model forecasted the good data, but I am encountering an issue with the forecasted data. Specifically, some of them are negative.

Example you find below:

```r
fit.lm <- train(Additional_Revenue~., data=dataset, method="lm", 
    metric=metric, preProc=c("range"), trControl=trainControl)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a reproducible example of what's going on, for example by providing a subset of your data so that others can examine the modeling and the results. I suspect this is because you are using a simple linear-regression model, which has no limitation on the sign of predictions, to data that have some observations close to 0. Without your providing more details, however, it's hard to be sure. Also, please edit the question to say more about what your outcome variable `Additional_Revenue` represents.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using a simple linear model on untransformed data, which can predict values in $(-\infty, \infty)$ even if this never happens in the training data (because extreme combinations of predictor values such as high values for things with a large negative coefficient - even if they occur in the training data but esp. at the edge of it/outside of it - may lead to negative predictions). Many things could solve this such as log-transforming inputs (assuming you never even have zeros).

Comment: Note that additive noise on the log scale is multiplicative on the linear scale, which may or may nor be what OP wants.